# Setting different CSS property on one table.cell.innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be a stupid question with no answer but I thought I'll give it a try anyway.

I am looping through a list containing strings that looks something like "1H 20MIN" and adding them to table cells through the innerHTML property, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
    myTable.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML = list[i];   
}
```

My goal is to have the numbers (in this case 1 and 20) in one font and the text (in this case H and MIN) in another font.

Can this be done somehow or can you give me some advice on how to structure my code/table differently?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put either the digits or the non-digits in `span` elements with an appropriate class name, and style them with CSS that way.

For insance, putting the digits in spans:

```
myTable.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML = list[i].replace(/\d+/g, "<span class=num>$&</span>");
```

...then style `.num`.

Example:

```js
var str = "1H 20MIN";
document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = str.replace(/\d+/g, "<span class=num>$&</span>");
```

```css
div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: green;
}
.num {
  font-family: serif;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="ex"></div>
```

Comment: Darn I'm late again to Crowder! and the solution is so elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can start by programmatically detecting the numeric character groups, then generate spans appropriately:

```js
var sExample = '1H 20MIN';
var arrSpanGroups = [];
var sHtml = '';

function getSpanGroups(string) {
  var arrGroups = [];
  var oWorkingGroup = {
    isNumeric: false,
    items: []
  }

  string.split('').forEach(function(sLetter) {
    handleCharacter(sLetter, oWorkingGroup, arrGroups);
  });

  arrGroups.push({
    text: oWorkingGroup.items.join(''),
    isNumeric: oWorkingGroup.isNumeric
  });

  //arrGroups.push(oWorkingGroup.items.join('')); //add the last group
  arrGroups.splice(0, 1); //get rid of the first empty item;

  return arrGroups;
}

function handleCharacter(sLetter, oWorkingGroup, arrGroups) {
  if (oWorkingGroup.isNumeric === isNumeric(sLetter)) { //they are both numbers or letters, group them
    oWorkingGroup.items.push(sLetter);
  } else { //they are differnt, end working group and start new
    arrGroups.push({
      text: oWorkingGroup.items.join(''),
      isNumeric: oWorkingGroup.isNumeric
    });

    oWorkingGroup.isNumeric = isNumeric(sLetter);
    oWorkingGroup.items = [sLetter];
  }
}

function isNumeric(sLetter) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(sLetter)) && isFinite(sLetter);
}

function spanGroupsToHtml(arrGroups) {
  var sHtmlToReturn = '';

  arrGroups.forEach(function(oGroup) {
    if (oGroup.isNumeric) {
      sHtmlToReturn += '<span class="mathy">' + oGroup.text + '</span>'
    } else {
      sHtmlToReturn += '<span class="charactery">' + oGroup.text + '</span>'
    }
  });

  return sHtmlToReturn;
}

arrSpanGroups = getSpanGroups(sExample);
sHtml = spanGroupsToHtml(arrSpanGroups);
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = sHtml;
```

```css
/* #christmas */

.mathy {
  color: red;
}

.charactery {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- pretend this is a row or cell or w/e -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add to the code to output the numbers and letters in separate spans with classes to suit.

I'll add a code example later on mobile at the moment. However the output would look something like this

```
<span class='time'>1<span class='letters'>HR</span> 20<span class='letters'>MIN</span> </span>
```